# How to insert id of every iteration of one table into anohter table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table ticket and testticket,item. In ticket i have insert data with two date and have different id like

```
TICKET TABLE (DATA INSERT)

ID      DATE

1     2019-08-01

2     2019-08-08
```

```
ITEM TABLE

items_id | item type

1        | Cmputer

2        | Computer1
```

these both tables are fine, but in `testticket` table I want that when I insert data in TICKET table on each id of ticket table there should be data in `testticket`

for example, data should be like this.

```
Test ticket table

ID     | DATE        |ticketid  |itenname

1     2019-08-01     |  1        |Computer

2     2019-08-08     |  2        |Computer    

3     2019-08-01     |  1        |Computer1

4     2019-08-08     |  2        |Computer1
```

but when I used this code it's showing me `ticketid` 1 in all test ticket records

```
$sql="select * from items";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'] ,$sql );
$dates = splitDates($min, $max,$parts);

foreach ($dates as $value) {
  $date= "$value";
    $sql1="insert into tickets (date) values('$date')";
 if ($GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql1) === TRUE) {

 $last_id = $GLOBALS['conn']->insert_id;


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

   foreach ($dates as $value) {
    // $i++;
    $name= $row['itemtype'];
    $date= "$value";
    $sql="insert into glpi_testticket (name,date,tid) 
   values('$name','$date','$last_id')";

    $query3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql ) or 
    die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['conn']));
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the first query. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your data model seems to make rather little sense to begin with. Why does your testticket table contain date and itemname again? Those are already kept in the other two tables, so why this redundancy?

Comment: This whole code is rather a mess. A foreach loop over $dates (we have no idea what that actually contains), inside of that a while loop going over the records initially read from the items table, and then inside another foreach loop, _again_ over $dates … hard to imagine that making actual sense in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Your while loop will only loop over the item records once, in the first iteration of the outer foreach loop. After that, trying to fetch a record from $result will only ever return null, because you did loop over all the records in the result set once already. You would need to position the record pointer at the beginning again, to be able to loop over the result again. You get a `1` in all records you insert, _because_ that while loop runs only once. That you still get four new records, is due to the foreach-while-foreach construct you created here.

Comment: @misorude can u do this with code please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ticket;
CREATE TABLE ticket
(ticket_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ticket VALUES
(1,'2019-08-01'),
(2,'2019-08-08');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;
CREATE TABLE item
(item_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,item_type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO item VALUES
(1,'Computer'),
(2,'Computer1');

SELECT * FROM ticket;
+-----------+------------+
| ticket_id | date       |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | 2019-08-01 |
|         2 | 2019-08-08 |
+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM item;
+---------+-----------+
| item_id | item_type |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Computer  |
|       2 | Computer1 |
+---------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM ticket,item;
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
| ticket_id | date       | item_id | item_type |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
|         1 | 2019-08-01 |       1 | Computer  |
|         2 | 2019-08-08 |       1 | Computer  |
|         1 | 2019-08-01 |       2 | Computer1 |
|         2 | 2019-08-08 |       2 | Computer1 |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Only one SELECT was harmed in the making of this result. It could just as well have been an INSERT instead.